# connect the user to his google drive by email and password using nodejs

Tags: node.js, google-drive-api, google-oauth

I'm trying to develop web app file management for that I want each user to be able to connect his google drive account I know that there is Oauth20_authorize but the user will need to provide client_id client_secret
what I need is to connect it only by email and password and have all permission read and write.

is it possible to implement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are a little confused as to how to access google APIs.

> I know that there is Oauth20_authorize but the user will need to provide client_id client_secret

The user does not provide the client id and client secret. You must register your application on google cloud console and [create web application credentials](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pBVAyU4pZOU).  Your application owns the client id and client secrete.

Then your application will be able to request consent of the user to access their google drive account.

> what I need is to connect it only by email and password and have all permission read and write.

You can not connect to a users private data using their email and password. this is called client login and was shut down by google in 2015.

You must use Oauth2 to access a users data.

May i suggest for starters that you follow the [node.js quickstart](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/quickstart/nodejs)
It will show you how to create a single user app.  After that you can alter it for multi user.

```
const fs = require('fs');
const readline = require('readline');
const {google} = require('googleapis');

// If modifying these scopes, delete token.json.
const SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly'];
// The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
// created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
// time.
const TOKEN_PATH = 'token.json';

// Load client secrets from a local file.
fs.readFile('credentials.json', (err, content) => {
  if (err) return console.log('Error loading client secret file:', err);
  // Authorize a client with credentials, then call the Google Drive API.
  authorize(JSON.parse(content), listFiles);
});

/**
 * Create an OAuth2 client with the given credentials, and then execute the
 * given callback function.
 * @param {Object} credentials The authorization client credentials.
 * @param {function} callback The callback to call with the authorized client.
 */
function authorize(credentials, callback) {
  const {client_secret, client_id, redirect_uris} = credentials.installed;
  const oAuth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2(
      client_id, client_secret, redirect_uris[0]);

  // Check if we have previously stored a token.
  fs.readFile(TOKEN_PATH, (err, token) => {
    if (err) return getAccessToken(oAuth2Client, callback);
    oAuth2Client.setCredentials(JSON.parse(token));
    callback(oAuth2Client);
  });
}

/**
 * Get and store new token after prompting for user authorization, and then
 * execute the given callback with the authorized OAuth2 client.
 * @param {google.auth.OAuth2} oAuth2Client The OAuth2 client to get token for.
 * @param {getEventsCallback} callback The callback for the authorized client.
 */
function getAccessToken(oAuth2Client, callback) {
  const authUrl = oAuth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
    access_type: 'offline',
    scope: SCOPES,
  });
  console.log('Authorize this app by visiting this url:', authUrl);
  const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout,
  });
  rl.question('Enter the code from that page here: ', (code) => {
    rl.close();
    oAuth2Client.getToken(code, (err, token) => {
      if (err) return console.error('Error retrieving access token', err);
      oAuth2Client.setCredentials(token);
      // Store the token to disk for later program executions
      fs.writeFile(TOKEN_PATH, JSON.stringify(token), (err) => {
        if (err) return console.error(err);
        console.log('Token stored to', TOKEN_PATH);
      });
      callback(oAuth2Client);
    });
  });
}

/**
 * Lists the names and IDs of up to 10 files.
 * @param {google.auth.OAuth2} auth An authorized OAuth2 client.
 */
function listFiles(auth) {
  const drive = google.drive({version: 'v3', auth});
  drive.files.list({
    pageSize: 10,
    fields: 'nextPageToken, files(id, name)',
  }, (err, res) => {
    if (err) return console.log('The API returned an error: ' + err);
    const files = res.data.files;
    if (files.length) {
      console.log('Files:');
      files.map((file) => {
        console.log(`${file.name} (${file.id})`);
      });
    } else {
      console.log('No files found.');
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: I manage to connect my account to the app but the problem is when each user of my app wants to connect his account he must enable google drive API and create credentials then prove the app with the client id and the client secret so this will be complicated steps for users

Comment: Each user should use your credentials not their own.   Application credentials are created by the developer.  Not by the user.  Your system just needs to change the TOKEN_PATH  storage for each user so that you have different credentials for each user using your system.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hBC_tVJIx5w   <-- if you want to understand Oauth2 this may help

Comment: so before everything I have to make the user connect with his google account then use the authorization that I got from that and use it to access google drive, right?

Comment: Yes you register your app on google developer console. google gives you credentials that identify your app to the user.    The user then runs your app containing your credentials  google returns to you an access token which gives you access to the users data.